# Why is horizontal scroll bar visible and vertical isn't?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, transform, microsoft-edge

With HTML below, why is horizontal scroll bar visible and vertical isn't?

This is true for Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not for Edge where both scroll bars aren't visible.

To me, it will be logical that both scroll bars aren't visible as it is in Edge browser.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="transform: translate(150px, 150px);">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -25px; top: -25px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: blue;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `div` has height 0 because its only inner element is a `div` with `position: absolute`. By default, `div` elements have width 100% and height to be the minimum to comport all inner elements, but elements with position absolute or fixed don't need to be comported inside their parent container, so they don't contribute with their container's height.

If you want the vertical scrollbar to show up, you can either force the second div's height to something greater than 300px or add more child elements with other types of position.